# Could not load library msvcrt-ruby240.dll

Tags: ruby, vim

I have install the last version of the `x86` version of `vim 8` and I have an issue whith the `ruby integration`.
My plugins like `LustyExplorer` can’t work and when I enter

```
:ruby –version
```

I got the following error :

```
E370: Could not load library msvcrt-ruby240.dll  
E266 : Sorry, this command is disabled, the Ruby Library could not be loaded.
```

When I run

```
:version
```

I have : `+ruby/dyn` and

```
-DDYNAMIC_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_VER=24 -
DDYNAMIC_RUBY_DLL=\"msvcrt-ruby240.dll\"
```

Ruby is install in `C:\Ruby24` and the `bin` folder containing the `msvcrt-ruby240.dll` is in `%PATH%`.
I also tried to put in my `vimrc` file

```
set rubydll="C:\Ruby24\bin\msvcrt-ruby240.dll"
```

but I got the following error :

```
E370: Could not load Library
E266 : Sorry, this command is disabled, the Ruby Library could not be loaded.
```

Both `ruby` and `vim` are `x86`.

I am working on `windows 10`.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "Both ruby and vim are x86."?

Comment: Please do not ask the question here, at vim-use and in the vim issue tracker

Comment: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2660
Add C:\Ruby24\bin\ruby_builtin_dlls to the PATH solve the issue.

Comment: @frantz this should have been an answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is @frantz answer:

> github.com/vim/vim/issues/2660 Add C:\Ruby24\bin\ruby_builtin_dlls to the PATH solve the issue.